# How do I interpret the zero-g level change vs temperature specification for this accelerometer?

Tags: temperature, accelerometer, error

This is an extract from the datasheet of the MPU6050 sensor.
[image]

I was expecting the level change vs temperature to be in units of mg/<sup>o</sup>C. Instead, as you can see, the temperature range is specified separately as 0 to 70<sup>o</sup>C and the level is in mg. The sensitivity change w.r.t temperature for the same accelerator is given in units of %/<sup>o</sup>C. So this doesn't seem to be an error due to oversight.
My current interpretation is that this spec means that the manufacturer only observed the variation but wasn't able to characterize it. What do you think?

Comment: It's the maximum deviation within that temperature range. And it's not that they weren't able to characterize it. They chose not to spend additional money to characterize it since it's just a cheap part meant for use in smartphones and game controllers, not IMUs.

Comment: It appears the middle column is typical and may be nonlinear or unpredictable but given as per design but not verified.

Comment: @DKNguyen, maximum deviation is my interpretation as well. But I'm not completely convinced that it would have cost a lot of additional money to characterize this (especially since changes in sensitivity w.r.t t temperature have been specified properly). I find it more believable that the device behavior was itself too inconsistent to characterize, especially since it is an entry level part. But since I do not fully understand the underlying parameters leading to temperature variation, I could be completely wrong. :)

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, by "given as per design", do you mean results from device simulations, but not verified in lab?

Comment: It is not maximum since I guessed correctly that it was under the typical tolerance. (Column header missing) It means it was design to meet this by some standard deviation.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, my bad regarding the headers. I was entirely focused on the unexpected units.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [datasheet](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf), nothing is guaranteed. 
[image]

You can take the delta and divide it by the temperature change and get a number, but it won't accurately represent the temperature coefficient most likely. This is common on some components and can lead to headaches if you don't understand the specsmanship games. With a complex digital device it can be even worse because there might be some mechanism to compensate that behaves badly when you look closely at it. More 'analog' parts like precision resistors and crystals usually behave more like a quadratic or cubic at worst, but often **not** linear.

In many cases, the manufacturer will quote a number but buried in the documentation will explain (admit?) that it is using the "box method". In other words the drift could have a very high coefficient, say from 20 to 30°C but reverse at 30°C and go back negative as you get to 70°C. The "box" is the peak-to-peak deviation divided by the temperature change, not the peak coefficient.

The typical figures are **not guaranteed**. One rule of thumb on the typical figures, such as they are, that may or may not bite you, is that most (99.9% of units) will usually be within 3\$\sigma\$.

Comment: The implication being that there's no practical, reliable, accurate way to compensate for it. If they published a figure in mg/degree, somebody would inevitably measure temperature, add a correction, ...  wonder why their results were still inaccurate, and complain.